# Python debugger tells me value of Numpy array is "*** Newest frame"

Tags: python, numpy, pdb

What does this mean?

My function gets two numpy arrays from a python/c library. After that function call I turn on the debugger to find a bug, so I add the line to look at the two numpy arrays.

```
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

But for the values of one of the `arrays` `pdb` only returns the message `*** Newest frame`

PDB output:

```
(Pdb) type(d)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(Pdb) type(f)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(Pdb) f.shape
(3, 3, 17856)
(Pdb) d[0].shape
*** Newest frame
(Pdb) d[0]
*** Newest frame
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The command `d` is the [command for the debugger](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands) used to go down the stack to a 'newer frame'. It seems that the parsing cannot not handle this disambiguity.

Try renaming the variable `d`.

**EDIT**: Actually, the comments suggest much better handling than renaming.

Comment: or do `p d[0].shape` or `print d[0].shape`

Comment: Or use an exclamation mark if you want to use Python code in the debugger: `!d[0]`. Normally, anything you enter on the debugger cmdline is consider a *debugger* command, not Python (but the debugger is quite flexible). See near the end of the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).

Comment: The (unfortunately deleted) [answer by Alex E](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647464/1967396) has a very good suggestion for a workaround - simply type `print(d)` in the debugger. This answer would be stronger if it added that suggestion.

Comment: Funny I just hit the same issue, in the debugger, just by typind d = blah() which my fingers are sitting on all the time, so...... the variable was 'd' which I changed to 'xx' and all went happy.